# How to show HTML in radioButton in flex3/4

Tags: html, apache-flex, radio-button, flex4, flex3

I want to show underline and strikethrough text(<s>asd</s>b etc) in a radiobutton control, there is no htmlText property to make use of. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it this way:

```
<input type="radio" name="X" value="Y"><font style="text-decoration:line-through;">My Label</font>
```

Comment: There is no attribute "type" in TextInput control, I think its a .Net thing. Besides this will make the whole text strikedthrough whereas the requirement is to make a part of it.